# Mediator pattern- import wizard c#

Tags: c#, mediator

i need to build a very simple wizard that will import a text file into a application in three steps and i need to use a mediator pattern. Im just wondering if there are some example applications or some tutorials or documentation. i tryed to search for some on the internet but did not find any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this one](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMediator.aspx). Shows really nice how to implement this pattern.

Comment: remember to accept my answer if it helps ;) If not let me know.. I'll try to figure it out with you :)